# Short layover in Paris - do I have time to visit the city?

Tags: airports, layovers, paris, culture

I have a 7½ layover in Paris en route to Toronto, I want to visit Musee Picasso, will it be possible, to do it within this time, also I am a Canadian passport holder will I be allowed to get out of the airport?

Comment: Excellent plan, excellent taste!  Imminently doable. You didn't give the details but you will have to be tactically clever to avoid queues. With enough detailed planning you should be able to take in the Bastille also, your date is near their festival time.

Comment: Bastille not worth it, building no longer there.

Comment: I would guess that 7.5 hrs is very unfortunately just not enough time to go in and out to the city from CDG.   You could *maybe just* make it if you were a local, you know, and really knew your way around.  But you'd only have a very short time in the museum.  It sucks someone booked that ticket for you.  You could have so easily organized a sensible shorter layover, or, a longer layover so that you could go in to town.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the website of French Diplomaty](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/venir-en-france/formalites-d-entree-en-france/) **Canadians do not have to ask for a visa to enter the Schengen zone** thank to the european regulation 539/2001 [french version](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2001:081:0001:0007:FR:PDF) /  [english version](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2001:081:0001:0007:EN:PDF). The stay must last **less than three months**. This regulation list countries for which a visa is required and the countries for which a visa is not required. The [website of French Diplomaty](http://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/venir-en-france/formalites-d-entree-en-france/article/les-etrangers-titulaires-d-un-passeport-ordinaire-dispenses-de-l-obligation-de) reproduces the latter. Nevertheless, the [Consulat général de France à Montréal](http://www.consulfrance-montreal.org/Ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa-pour-la) adds that you should be able to provide the same papers as if you were asking for a visa to the custom at CDG ([listed here](http://www.consulfrance-montreal.org/Visa-de-court-sejour-pour). In particular, bring a photo, copies of your 3 last paychecks or business registration, bank statement over the last 3 months and your return ticket. You may not even need it...

Fortunately, the Picasso museum is not very far from the RER B line, "les Halles" station. The train takes approximately 40 minutes. There is a train at least every 15 minutes. See the [vianavigo website](https://www.vianavigo.com/#criteria=5&mrq=&id=14&departure=A%C3%A9roport+CDG+Terminal+2E,+Le+Mesnil-Amelot&departureType=Site&departureCity=Le+Mesnil-Amelot&departureCoordX=&departureCoordY=&departureExternalCode=16357&departureCityCode=77990&arrival=Mus%C3%A9e+National+Picasso,+Paris&arrivalType=Site&arrivalCity=Paris&arrivalCityCode=75000&arrivalCoordX=&arrivalCoordY=&arrivalExternalCode=8638&date=16/06/2016&dateFormat=dd/MM/yyyy&sens=1&hour=23&min=35&moreCriterions=false&via=&viaType=&viaCity=&viaCityCode=&viaExternalCode=&train=true&_train=on&rer=true&_rer=on&metro=true&_metro=on&bus=true&_bus=on&tram=true&_tram=on&walkSpeed=1&spcar=%C3%A2&hpx=1&hat=1&L=0&submitSearchItinerary=&ajid=/stif_web_carto/comp/itinerary/search.html_): going to the Picasso museum should take 1h15 including 35 minutes of walk.

Yet, there are some risks that must not be neglected:

- The Charles de Gaulle aiport is large and the immigration may be very slow. ->1h30
- The train can be delayed and it often takes more than 40 minutes to reach Paris. "les Halles" station is a large underground station with a shopping mall on its top. Streets in Paris are not straight and getting lost is possible -> 3h/3h30 of moving. If the train to go back to the airport is cancelled, take a taxi [(50€)](http://www.parisaeroport.fr/passagers/acces/paris-charles-de-gaulle/taxi/paris-cdg-taxi).
- The security to go back to the international area can be very long. [The limiting registration time of Air France at Charles de Gaulle 2 is 60 minutes](http://www.airfrance.fr/FR/fr/common/guidevoyageur/aeroport/enregistrement_hle.htm).Lastly, [The aiport advices 75-90 minutes for correspondences between terminals](http://cdgfacile.com/informations-passagers/correspondance-a-cdg/informations-pratiques/) -> 1h30. This is a minimum.

Hence, **if your stay in Paris lasts only 7h30, you may enjoy a 1h30 hour visit of the museum**... But if you want to visit it, you will have to rush ! You can [book your ticket to avoid the queue](http://www.museepicassoparis.fr/individuels-musee-et-visioguide/)

The decision is up to you: if you are not an experienced traveller or if you are reluctant to worry about being on time, don't do it! **You must be aware that this great idea can become a really bad trip.** If you want to enjoy the city of Paris and its museums, consider spending a few days there!

Comment: You definitely don't need to bring a photo, form or proof of travel insurance. You might *theoretically* be asked to produce evidence that you have sufficient financial means for your time in the Schengen area and to go back to your country of origin, a valid purpose for your stay and the intention to leave before 90 days (it's 90 days now, not 3 months) and you can legally be refused entry if you do not fulfil any of these requirements. But in practice, you will be asked a couple of questions, your passport will be scanned and stamped and that's it.

Comment: Another small detail: Can customs really be slow? I almost never had to wait more than a few moments anywhere in the EU, mostly you just walk through. Usually, what can be slow are immigration controls, especially for non-EU citizens, is that what you mean?

Comment: @francis I think you are confusing customs with immigration.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : yes, i must have confused customs with immigration. Thanks!