# 9 hour layover in Paris CDG on way to Cairo from LAX

Tags: layovers, paris, cdg

I am a US citizen with US passport flying out of LAX late September on a Friday afternoon and arriving in CDG around 9am Saturday staying for a 9 hour layover before my flight to Cairo on Air France. Can I leave CDG and visit Paris ? I see other similar questions but not specific to US passports since US is not part of Schengen.

Comment: There is a train station station at CDG with regular trains that seem to take about 30 minutes. I am unsure though whether you would be allowed to and whether you have to pick up and drop your luggage off etc. and whether you'd have time to leave the airport, get there, and do anything meaningful before coming back.

Comment: Thank you. Yes wondering if I would be allowed customs / visa wise. The luggage will be in transit so I wouldn’t see it.

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly doable and you can enter France without a visa, being in transit is not an issue. The situation is a bit different (transit to a Schengen destination, visa required due to the person's citizenshio) but the info in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62220/9hour-layover-in-paris-can-i-go-out-of-the-airport?rq=1 can be useful.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71256/short-layover-in-paris-do-i-have-time-to-visit-the-city?rq=1 and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43412/is-a-7-hour-layover-in-paris-long-enough-to-leave-the-airport-and-sightsee?rq=1

Comment: There are also no Covid-related restrictions at the moment, you do not even need to prove you are vaccinated (as visitors to the US still do, AFAIK).

Comment: @relaxed I think you answered it thank you!!

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket? If they are not that would change the situation regarding checked luggage.

Comment: Just to clarify the main issue of the question: As a US citizen you can enter France just by showing your passport. No visa, authorization or pre-approval needed.

Comment: @ jcaron yes both flights are on same ticket. Thanks

Comment: @hilmar Thanks for clarifying that was a big part of my question. All the best.